# Calculating the Poynting vector for a line charge moving along its length

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

The problem reads:

*An infinitely long thin wire carrying a uniform linear static charge density $\lambda$ is placed along the z-axis. The wire is set into motion along its length with a uniform velocity $\vec{v}$ = v $\hat{k}$. Calculate the poynting vector $\vec{S}$ = $\frac{1}{\mu_o}$ $(\vec{E} \times \vec{B)}$ at a distance $a$ from the wire.* (Figure 8.1, attached)

[image]

Here is my attempt:

For the sake of simplicity, let me consider the fields at a point on the y-z plane. The electric field caused by the wire at a point on the axis will be given by :

$$\vec{E} = \frac{\lambda}{2\pi\varepsilon_0a}\hat{j}$$

Also, as the line charge is now translating in the positive z direction, there is also a current. Considering any cross section of the wire, in a time interval $dt$ a charge equivalent to $\lambda vdt$ would have crossed it, hence the current should be $i=\lambda v$ and the magnetic field due to this wire at the same point would be,
$$\vec{B} = -\frac{\mu_0 \lambda v}{2\pi a}\hat{i}$$

Hence the Poynting vector would be,
$$\vec{S} = \frac{1}{\mu_o}(\vec{E} \times \vec{B)} = +\frac{\mu_0 \lambda v^2}{4\pi^2 a^2 \varepsilon_0}\hat{k}$$

The given answer is however,

$$\vec{S} = -\frac{\mu_0 \lambda v^2}{4\pi^2 a^2 \varepsilon_0}\hat{k}$$

What has caused this error of sign? Have I misrepresented any directions of the electric/magnetic fields? Help would be appreciated.

(Also, I am quite new to poynting vectors so please do consider that when answering!)

Comment: If someone could share a reason for downvoting, that would be great.

Comment: Please? At least tell me how it violates the policy? Is there anything wrong with this question? Is there anything wrong with how I have framed my attempt? Does it not match up to the exceptional standards of this great community?

Comment: I know this is not a homework help site, which is why I have given my complete attempt. Clearly I am not asking anyone to do this question for me! All I am asking is why my answer is incorrect, which is probably because of a conceptual error I have made. Doesn't this community exist for this very purpose, to discuss physics and clarify the concepts related to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the answer given is wrong, because the directions of both vectors are ok and I have tried different cases of the problem, even changed to cylindrical coordinates and the Poynting vectors I get are always without the negative sign.

Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm pretty sure the problem is in the answer. Perhaps someone else can help you a bit more.

Comment: It's not my post, but ok.

Comment: Sorry I had two similar tabs open at the same time. In any case, the answer section is only for answers.

Comment: @Biophysicist Could you help me out here please? Also, why is my question downvoted?

Comment: Anyway, since nobody else is bothering to help out or explain their reasons for the downvotes, I'm accepting this answer. Feel free to delete this question or whatever you want to do with it.